# Creating a crontab for logging all processes and saving them to a log

Tags: scripts, cron, automation

How would I create a crontab that logs all processes and saves them to a log file called `/home/documents/test.log`?

I've tried this:

```
22 14 * * *  ps >> /home/documents/test.log
```

but it does not work. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Yout need to call the command as follow:

```
22 14 * * * ps -ef >> /home/documents/test.log
```

or with date/time information

```
22 14 * * * (/bin/date;/bin/ps -ef) >> /home/documents/test.log
```

Answer (score 1):

First off the path to your file is probably wrong. The way it is structured now it appears to say "top level home directory for the user named `documents`".

What you really want is `/home/$USER/Documents/test.log`

Where:

- $USER = your user name
- Documents starts with a capital `D` not a lower-case `d`

Keep in mind running `ps` with no parameters will only show the current process not all the other processes. I've learned to use `ps -aux`.

Therefore your `cron` command would be:

```
22 14 * * *  ps -aux >> /home/$USER/Documents/test.log
```

Don't forget to change $USER to your real user ID.

To check output you can use:

```
cat /home/$USER/Documents/test.log
```